# INTEGER PRIMARY KEY has high insert cost

Tags: sqlite

Edit: My original post was mistaken; The issue is simply one of working set size and random access causing a large number of pages to be accessed.

Over a larger test range the quadratic model diverged and became more linear. Additionally, I made a mistake and thought I had already ruled out the random insert order as the cause, but that configuration was wrong and monotonic insertion was indeed faster.

---

[This graph shows the behavior of different column types.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwJbT.png)

Test setup:

- SQLite version: 3.37.2 2022-01-06
- Language: C++.
- Test data: A contiguous sequence of unique 32-bit integers, shuffled.
- Insert method: Prepared query, 100k transaction batch, 20 rows per statement with bound parameters
- PRAGMAs: Safe defaults with exclusive locking mode and memory temp store.
- DB: Blank test database on local filesystem, NVMe SSD

Variations tested:

```
1. CREATE TABLE integers (value INTEGER);
2. CREATE TABLE integers (value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
3. CREATE TABLE integers (value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) WITHOUT ROWID;
4. CREATE TABLE integers (value INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Approximate fit curves:

```
1:   Linear:     0             + 2.5E-7 * N
2+3: Quadratic:  1.35E-7 * N^2 + 1.8E-6 * N
4:   Quadratic:  1.35E-7 * N^2 + 3.7E-6 * N
```

My expectation going from the `INTEGER` table (1) to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `WITHOUT ROWID` (2, 3) was this should be faster, due to the merger of the value and the rowid columns giving somewhat better page usage. To my surprise, using either form cripples insert performance with a quadratic cost term, eventually becoming unusable. (Performance is identical for versions 2 and 3 as I believe they specify the same thing.)

Version (4) demonstrates the same behavior, but has double the linear cost component, reflective of how `INT PRIMARY KEY` is not special cased in the same way as `INTEGER` PK, and results in a secondary index insertion in addition to the clustered table. I thought that the primary key slowness was a special problem that only occurred when the `WITHOUT ROWID` behavior is used, but moving the constraint to the secondary index does not fix the problem.

Comment: You didn't post the *actual* test code. The actual data matters. If you add rows in the *middle* of an indexed table, the database will have to move stuff around as it updates the index. Besides, indexes are used to speed up queries at the cost of more expensive inserts. Ordered inserts are faster than random inserts. When you have lots of data, it's often faster to drop/disable indexes and re-enable them after the load

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic cost is due to the shuffled inserts.

Sqlite tables and indexes are stored in Btree structures.

Table (1) has a hidden `ROWID` column and the `value` column. Every new record is added at the end of the table, in the same page, with increasing ROWIDs. Apart from the occasional Btree rebalances, page reads and writes are kept to a minimum.

Tables (2) and (3) are the same thing: `ROWID` is not present and `value` is instead the key of the table, which means that the table is actually **clustered on the value column**. If you inserted the values in sequential order you would have the same performance as in (1), but inserting them in random order will cause constant access to a lot of different pages and the need not only to seek but also to update the Btree much more often.

Table (4) is the same as (1) but, since `value` is declared as a PRIMARY KEY, an index on `value` is automatically created and mantained. So you have the linear cost of sequentially updating the table as in (1) plus the cost of randomly updating the Btree index as in (2).

Comment: I apologize for giving mistaken information. I thought I had tested shuffled vs. unshuffled keys to no effect, but I hadn't tested this properly. Monotonic insertion was indeed faster.

However, this is still confusing. Even with worst case behavior, random insertion into a B-tree should be log(N) per element, resulting in N*log(N) total insert time, but the observed performance implies individual insert cost proportional to N. I have been reading through the SQLite btree implementation to try and find any situation in which this would be possible.

Comment: After testing on larger data I found the quadratic fit diverged and the behavior became more linear, consistent with working set size crossing cache boundaries. An in-memory database was closer to linear and continuous. So I think it's just a function of the number of pages being accessed. It's unfortunate my first test was faulty and I was chasing something that wasn't a big problem.